# Rails mail tutorial, along with the required settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm new to RoR, writing a simple app.  Need to implement mail functionality the usual register/forgot password stuff. I have googled, but haven't got a complete tutorial yet.  Most of the tutorials teach how to send mail, but don't help out with the settings.  can someone suggest a good tutorial, complete with settings?

I'm on ubuntu 9.04, would like to use my dev box as the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting using Ruby on Rails and am using Ubuntu too.
From my research, I've found http://modrails.com/ is the best solution to host rails on ubuntu / apache. Their documentation is great to get the server up and running.

From there, I've found the best Rails Tutorial is the official ones, which can be found at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/.

A good way to also start learning stuff is to look at source code of other apps, some of which can be found at http://opensourcerails.com/.